# Extjs form performance problem

Tags: extjs

We use big input forms with couple of input fields and run into performance problems. The exact problem is the render time of the form. It takes couple of seconds (4-10sec) to display the form.
We use multi column layout and ~30 combo fields loaded by json datastore and another ~10 input fields.
The render process is so slow so I can see the alignment and display process of the form. Is there any method to speed up the display process?

Comment: I have to ask, how usable is 30 combo fields anyhow? That's a hell of a lot of fields for any form.

Comment: yes, that's a lots of fields, but it makes sense to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting all the combobox data in a single slot, then load the data using the `store.load` method

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the data loaded by the JSONStores is causing the alignment to change? Turn off all the JSONStores and then measure the render process - you'll see that it takes quite awhile for the browser to make 30 back-end requests!

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest your stores are the problem.  Have you tried FireFox?  Or as @JJ recommended, don't load the stores and see what happens.  I would also suggest rendering your forms lazily, but it seems like your problem involves the stores.

I have seen similar slowness when loading stores (usually backend queries taking lots of time).  So, I created a single AJAX call to retrieve all store data.  In the AJAX callback, parse the contents of the payload and distribute appropriately to each store.

Comment: We use Firefox + Firebug for development. I don't think that the original problem is the json stores and requests (see my reply above).   I think the slowness comes from rendering and layout. It can be seen by eyes that it tries to align/resize parts of the form to fit together. Although already I've said 3.1 version resolved most of our problems.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for someone:

We have same problem with multiple checkboxes and [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153565-ExtJS-Performance-Best-Practices/page2) post helps us to solve it.

Each time, when `Form` or other container adds an element - it's layout recalculates. This causes render issue when there is a lot of elements.

So, you can:

1. Add all children at one-time:

```js
    container.add(panel, button, grid);
```

2. Suspend layout recalculation:

```js
    container.suspendLayout = true;
    addSomething();
    container.suspendLayout = false;
    container.doLayout();
```